# Add values of two columns in one table and inserting into third column

Tags: sql, database, plsql, analytics

I have table name STUDENTS having four column ( name , maths marks , eng, marks , total )
I want to get sum of marks in maths and english in column 'total'.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have data in maths_marks and eng_marks columns, you can go for update statement like below :

```
update students set total = (maths_marks + eng_marks);
```

Else if you want to insert as a new row,

```
insert into students values ('Querty', 85, 90, 85 + 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
[name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[maths] [int] NULL,
[eng] [int] NULL,
[total] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Prameters

```
declare @name varchar(100)
declare @mathsmarks int
declare @engmarks int
```

Here we have set values to parametrs

```
set @name='ccc'
set @mathsmarks=80
set @engmarks=80
```

Insert Query

```
insert into students values (@name, @mathsmarks, @engmarks, @mathsmarks + @engmarks);
```

Select Query

```
select * from Students
```

Output

```
ccc 80  80  160
```

Comment: Its not necessary to write ON PRIMARY. here we have not applied PRIMARY KEY on any column. but if you want, you can use.The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table. @Kunwar Gurkirat Singh